# How can I call arm-none-eabi-gdb with -x parameter

Tags: linux, arm, visual-studio-code, cross-compiling

I want to call `arm-none-eabi-gdb` with -x parameter when launch debugger after installing cortex-debug. How can I do in `launch.json` or `setting.json`, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You may try adding the following task to our tasks.json the following:

```
 {
        "label": "flash",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "arm-none-eabi-gdb",
        "args": [               
            "-x=\"${workspaceFolder}/.vscode/flash.gdb\"",                
        ],
        "group": "build",
        "problemMatcher": [],
        "dependsOn":["build"]
    },
```

(of course this assume you have another task called "build" and that your "flash" task depends on it. this is just an example of how to add the -x argument)